# Courier does not show IMAP Maildir folders

Tags: imap, maildir, courier

I am in the process of moving a courier IMAP server from one machine to another. Maildirs have been set up, all the messages have been copied successfully. There are a few IMAP folders that show up in the mail clients on the old server, but they are not visible on the new destination server. I compared the client/server communication side by side in Wireshark and it turned out that the IMAP LIST command

```
4 list "" "INBOX.*"
```

returns the list of IMAP folders on **both** machines. The IMAP LSUB command, however, on the destination machine returns an empty set while on the source machine it also returns a list of all Maildir folders.

```
5 lsub "" "INBOX.*"
```

Anyone has a clue, why the LSUB command does not return the subfolders on one machine, while on the other it does?

Note: The courierimapsubscribed file in the Maildir on both servers are exactly the same, both contain all folders.

*Source: courier-imap 4.10 armhf;
Destination: courier-imap 4.18 amd64*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve the issue bei creating and deleting a folder in the Maildir using the e-mail client (Thunderbird, in that case). Restarted the client and all folders showed up. Strange detail: the courierimapsubscribed file was completely the same, before and after.